# Angular, toggle text with a 'See More' button in Angular material table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I've implemented the function to toggle the description, when user clicks 'See More' it will display the full description.
**But the problem is, it toggles all of them simultaneously.**

[image: This is what I have now]

[image: Clicking a single See More button will toggle them all]

This is what I have in the html file:

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
            The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
    
      <!-- Category Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Category</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          {{ element.category }}
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Subcategory Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="subcategory">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Subcategory</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          {{ element.subcategory }}
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Email Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Email</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.email }}</td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Subject Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="subject">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Subject</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.subject }}</td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Description Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Description</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" id="description">
          <p *ngIf="show">{{ element.description }}</p>
          <a mat-button href="javascript:void()" (click)="toggleText()">
            {{ buttonName }}</a>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Image Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="images">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Images</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <img
            *ngFor="let image of element.image"
            [src]="image"
            height="150"
            width="200px"
            style="margin: 3px"
          />
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
```

and this is the function for toggling the button in TypeScript file:

```
    toggleText() {
    this.show = !this.show;
    if (!this.show) {
      this.buttonName = 'See More';
    } else {
      this.buttonName = 'Hide';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shows all of them because you have a single boolean variable (`this.show`) that controls whether the description is displayed or not. You need to keep track of the individual flags for each item. I propose to do that using an object instead:

```
public showDescription: { [key: number]: boolean } = {};
```

*Supposing that your elements actually have an `id` property of type `number`.*

The cell definition should now look like this, to acomodate the new map that we have:

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" id="description">
  <p *ngIf="showDescription[element.id]">{{ element.description }}</p>
    <a mat-button href="javascript:void()" (click)="toggleText(element.id)">
      {{ showDescription[element.id] ? 'Hide' : 'See More' }}</a>
</td>
```

The `toggleText` handler now needs to take in the element id as a parameter and update the map accordingly:

```
toggleText(elementId: number) {
  this.showDescription[elementId] = !this.showDescription[elementId];
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply, but I got this error in my console "`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')`. It successfully retrieve the ID for each row but I dont know why im getting the error of undefined.

Comment: Oh, sorry, apparently I forgot to initialize it. Check out the updated answer. You need to give `showDescription` an initial value of `{}` (empty object) to get rid of this error.